# Как можно генерировать отчет при определенном событии 1С?

Tags: 1с

Мне нужно, чтобы при изменении ролей или профилей создавался новый отчет по правам доступа. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого в конфигурации 1С есть `ПодпискаНаСобытие` (это процедура, которая выполняется при определенном событии)